# Django using timedelta to filter results in template

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm setting up a journal subscription shopping cart and would like users to be able to order subscriptions based on the distance from the current date.

Each subscription contains 3 issues. I'd like to give people the option to order 1 year starting with the current issue or 1 year starting with the next issue.

My model is fairly simple:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
  start_date = models.DateField(max_length=10)
  end_date = models.DateField(max_length=10)
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
  def __unicode__(self):
      return unicode(self.start_date)
```

Ideally the "Order 1 year starting with current" would look for a `Subscription` with a `start_date` in the past, but the most recent in the past.

The "Order 1 year starting with next" would return a `Subscription` with the `start_date` closest to the current date in the future.

How would I implement this kind of logic in the view?

Comment: why are your date fields `CharField`s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## views.py

```
class NextSubscription(View):
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            return Subscription.objects.filter(start_date__gt=date.today()).order_by("start_date")[0]
        except IndexError:
            raise Exception("No Next Subscription Found")

class CurrentSubscription(View):
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            return Subscription.objects.filter(start_date__lt=date.today()).order_by("-start_date")[0]
        except IndexError:
            raise Exception("No Current Subscription Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to put this in your `forms` logic rather than `views`.
I presume there is also an  `Issue` model, something like this:

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    issue_date = models.DateField()
    ....
```

Upon saving your `Subscription`, your `save()` should do something like this:

### forms.py

```
from models import Subscription
from django import forms
class SubscriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(SubscriptionForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if instance.start_from_next:  # You should add a start_from_next boolean field to know if user wants to start from previous or next issue
            the_issue = Issue.objects.filter(issue_date__gt=date.today()).order_by("start_date")[0]
        else:
            the_issue = Issue.objects.filter(issue_date__lt=date.today()).order_by("-start_date")[0]
        instance.start_date = the_issue.start_date
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Subscription
```